# Data Type Conversion from SQL Server to Oracle

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I am currently moving a product from SQL Server to Oracle. I am semi-familiar with SQL Server and know nothing about Oracle, so I apologize if the mere presence of this question offends anyone.

Inferring from this page, http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12151_01/doc.150/e12156/ss_oracle_compared.htm, it would seem that the data type conversion from SQL Server to Oracle should be:

REAL = FLOAT(24) -> FLOAT(63)

FLOAT(p) -> FLOAT(p)

TIMESTAMP -> NUMBER

NVARCHAR(n) -> VARCHAR(n*2)

NCHAR(n) -> CHAR(n*2)

Here are my questions regarding them:

For FLOAT, considering that FLOAT(p) -> FLOAT(p), wouldn't it also mean that FLOAT -> FLOAT(24)?

For TIMESTAMP, since Oracle also has its own version of it, wouldn't it be better that TIMESTAMP -> TIMESTAMP?

Finally, for NVARCHAR(n) and NCHAR(n), I thought the issue would be regarding Unicode. Then, again, since Oracle provides its own version of both, wouldn't it make more sense that NVARCHAR(n) -> NVARCHAR(n) and NCHAR(n) -> NCHAR(n)?

It would be much appreciated if someone were to elaborate on the previous 3 matters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that Oracle's CHAR and VARCHAR2 (always use VARCHAR2 instead of VARCHAR) already support Unicode - the document you've linked to advises converting to those from the SQL Server NCHAR and NVARCHAR datatypes.

The SQL Server TIMESTAMP isn't actually a timestamp at all - it's some kind of identifier based on the time that's just used to indicate that a row has changed - it can't be converted back into any kind of DATETIME (at least in a way that I know about).

For FLOAT, using 126 bytes would be enormous - since the developer tools automatically map SQL Server's FLOAT to Oracle's FLOAT(53), why not use that amount?

Comment: a SQL Server timestamp data type column is a random type value that will automatically change every time the row is changed, it is used to track changes.  When you load the data, you store this timestamp value, when you go back to update the data you can do `UPDATE... WHERE PK=@PK AND TimestampCol=@PreviousTimestamp`.  If no rows are affected, then data was changed by someone else since you loaded it.  Also, timestamp is being removed from SQL Server, because the name was confusing, it is being replaced by [rowversion (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This is more FYI than an answer to your question, but you're potentially going to run into a particularly painful difference between SQL Server and Oracle.  In SQL Server, you can define a string column (of whatever flavor) to not allow NULL values, and then insert zero-length (aka "blank") strings into that column, because SQL Server does not consider a blank string to be the same as a NULL.

Oracle *does* consider a blank string to be the same as a NULL, so Oracle will not let you insert blank values into a NOT NULL column.  This obviously causes problems when copying data from a table in SQL Server into its counterpart table in Oracle.  You choices for dealing with this are:

1. Set the offending string column in Oracle to allow NULL values (*so* not a good idea)
2. When copying the data, replace the blank strings with *something else* (I have no idea what you should use here)
3. Skip the offending rows and pretend you never saw them

I'd love to think that Oracle's choice to consider blank strings to be NULL (where they're alone among the major DBs) was to lock customers into their platform, but this one actually works in the opposite direction.  You can move a database from Oracle to something else without the blank=NULL difference causing any problems.

See this earlier question:  [Oracle considers empty strings to be NULL while SQL Server does not - how is this best handled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160904/oracle-considers-empty-strings-to-be-null-while-sql-server-does-not-how-is-this)

Comment: Thanks for your warning. I can't help but wonder if there are other similarly destructive conversions that will be required.

Comment: Also, string concatenation with null is different between SQL Server and Oracle. SQL Server 'A' + null yields null, Oracle 'A' || null yields 'A'.

Comment: Shannon: in Oracle's defense (I can't believe I'm saying this), the difference you mention at least follows logically from the blank=NULL difference I mentioned. Otherwise, there'd be no way to ever include blank strings in concatenations and get back a non-null result.

Comment: @BeginnerAmongBeginners: the blank=NULL thing is the only thing you really have to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

Following is not a direct answer to your question; but it is good to take a look at the sqlteam blog

[sqlteam - Datatypes translation between Oracle and SQL Server part 2: number](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jamesw/archive/2010/08/04/datatypes-translation-between-oracle-and-sql-server-part-2-number.aspx)

It has detailed explanation about how to handle `numbers`, etc.